# Delete Duplicates in MYSQL using a text column for comparison

Tags: mysql, duplicates, unique-key

We've got a database table that need a multiple column unique key. However, one of those columns is TEXT and has lengths as long as 1000 chars (so varchar won't work either). Because of the TEXT column, I can't actually have a unique key for those columns. What's a good way to remove duplicates? Of course, fast would be nice.

Comment: There is many, many questions here on this.

Comment: I really just want to find an efficient way to do this one thing. If you would like to answer several questions to explain your answer, I would be fine with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to use a `UNIQUE INDEX` to avoid duplicate.

Creating a new unique key on the over columns you need to have as uniques will automatically clean the table of any duplicates.

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE `table_name`
    ADD UNIQUE KEY `key_name`(`column_1`,`column_2`);
```

The `IGNORE` part does not allow the script to terminate after the first error occurs. And the default behavior is to delete the duplicates.

Comment: Because of the TEXT column, I can't actually have a unique key for those columns.

Answer (score 2):

Add a `unique` constraint as below:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE table1
 ADD UNIQUE unique_name(column1, comlumn1, column3 ... Text);
```

Here `IGNORE` will help in removing the duplicates while creating the constraint.

Comment: I sware that I don't copy / paste! But you was more quickly => +1

Comment: Because of the TEXT column, I can't actually have a unique key for those columns.

Comment: @gearhead_webdev: I think that recreating the table with `distinct` is next option i.e. rename the current table, create new as select distinct from the old renamed table. Will that work for you?

Comment: That 'works' but it takes a very long time to complete. That's what I'm currently doing though. I just need a better solution.